# Find a basis for a solution set of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm trying hard with this exercise, but it is breaking my back.

> Find a basis for the solution set of the given homogeneous linear system
>
> $3x_1+x_2+x_3=0$
>   $6x_1+2x_2+2x_3=0$
>   $-9x_1-3x_2-3x_3=0$

I do what I know I need to do. First I get the solution set of the system by reducing like this:

$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 2 & 2 \\
-9 & -3 & -3 \end{pmatrix} \leadsto \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \leadsto\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

So I know $\vec x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{3}r-\frac{1}{3}s\\
r\\
s\end{bmatrix}$

That being the general solution.

Now, giving the values for $r$ and $s$ according to the standard vectors $i$, $j$

$\vec x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{3}r-\frac{1}{3}s\\
r\\
s\end{bmatrix} = r \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{3}\\
1\\
0\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{3}\\
0\\
1\end{bmatrix}$

From my results, the basis will be:

$ ( \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{3}\\
1\\
0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{3}\\
0\\
1\end{bmatrix})$

But instead, the book answer (I'm self-studying )is:

$ ( \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
3\\
0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
3\end{bmatrix})$

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: You're basis isn't correct as you can't factor out the r that easily I think.  The other thought I had was that you may be missing a sign change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your expression for $\vec x$.  I think it should be $\vec x=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{3}r-\frac{1}{3}s \\r \\s \end{bmatrix}=r\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{3} \\1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{3} \\0 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I came to put a one right there :(

Comment: This still has a sign issue. Regards

Comment: I just made a one character edit: to add a negative sign before $\frac 13$ in the last vector. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, thanks @amWhy!

Comment: And since the book's answer is a scalar multiple of those vectors, is a basis considered equivalent to any scalar multiple of itself?

Comment: @user124384  I'm not sure in what sense you are using the term 'equivalent,' but, in general, one can scale the elements of any basis by any nonzero scalar to obtain a different basis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow this step.

$\vec x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{3}r-\frac{1}{3}s\\
r\\
s\end{bmatrix} = r \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{3}\\
1\\
0\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{3}\\
0\\
1\end{bmatrix}$

Wouldn't you want to write this as:

$\vec x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{3}r-\frac{1}{3}s\\
r\\
s\end{bmatrix} = r \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-1}{3}\\
1\\
0\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-1}{3}\\
0\\
1\end{bmatrix}$

If you write out the eigenvalues, you get $\lambda = 1, 0 , 0$

The corresponding eigenvectors are:

$(1, 0, 0), (-1/3, 0, 1), (-1/3, 1, 0)$ and these should look familiar to your solution.

Regards

Comment: I understand, completely...been there...felt that way too...But, we can't resist helping, regardless ;-)