# Determine a basis for the solution set of the homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

> Determine a basis for the solution set of the homogeneous system:
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> x_1 +x_2 +x_3 &=0\\
> 3x_1+3x_2+x_3 &=0\\
> 4x_1+4x_2+2x_3&=0
> \end{align*}$$
>
> Then the augmented matrix is:
>
> $$
>         \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
>         1 & 1 & 1 &0\\
>         3 & 3 & 1 &0\\
>         4 & 4 & 2 &0\\
>         \end{array}\right]
> $$
>
> Reduced Row Echelon Form $\to$
>
> $$
>         \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
>         1 & 1 & 0 &0\\
>         0 & 0 & 1 &0\\
>         0 & 0 & 0 &0\\
>         \end{array}\right]
> $$

I already looked at [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296600/find-a-basis-for-a-solution-set-of-a-linear-system) but it didn't help much. I am wondering can someone help to find basis (choosing some parameter for variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$) from RREF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equation in the Reduced Row Echelon Form tells you that we need $x_1+x_2=0$ and the second equation says $x_3=0$. So If we take $x_2=t$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ then we must have $x_1=-x_2=-t$ and $x_3=0$.

Thus we have a 1-dimensional solution space determined by the vector

$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(-1,1,0)$.

This follows from the above discussion since taking $x_2=t$ corresponds to scalar multiplication by t on $(-1,1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The equations to be satisfied are 
$x_1+ x_2+ x_3= 0$
$3x_1+ 3x_2+ x_3= 0$
$4x_1+ 4x_2+ x_3= 0$

The first thing I notice is that if we multiply the first equation by 3 and subtract the second equation we have $2x_3= 0$ so any solution to this system of equations must have $x_3= 0$.  Setting $x_3= 0$ in these equations, we have
$x_1+ x_2= 0$, $3x_1+ 3x_2= 0$, $4x_1+ 4x_2= 0$

all of which are equivalent to $x_1+ x_2= 0$ or $x_2= -x_1$.  Any solution to this system of equations is for the form $(x_1, x_2, x_3)= (x_1, -x_1, 0)= x_1(1, -1, 0)$.

That is a one dimensional subspace of $R^3$ with basis $\{(1, -1, 0)\}$.
(Of course, $\{(-1, 1, 0)\}$ is equivalent.)