# Computational Algorithm To Find Basis of Linear Equations Solution Set

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a set of linear equations and I am trying to find out the basis of solution space. For example [Check This One](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296600/find-a-basis-for-a-solution-set-of-a-linear-system). My question is that if there is an algorithm or process which is computationally implementable in a computer program.

Comment: If you want procedures which are already implemented, then you can check Mathematica, Matlab, sage, or numpy.linalg in python. You can also write your matrix into wolfram alpha and ask for its image. Probably Macaulay2 has a procedure as well, but apart from writing the program yourself (which, to be fair, can take a little time), these are the options I know.

Answer (score -1):

You may want
to have a look at [Gaussian algorithm](https://cp-algorithms.com/linear_algebra/linear-system-gauss.html) or similar pages in the Internet.

It seems that the following is a much better source:
[Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_20.html), search for *Function:* **linsolve ([expr_1, …, expr_m], [x_1, …, x_n])**